# Load EFI image using gnu-efi

Tags: c, boot, uefi, gnu-efi

I am writing a UEFI 'chainloader' to learn more about how it works.
I am using gnu-efi, and trying to load and start an EFI image. I want my main.efi to load and run hello.efi, located in the same ESP. I just don't understand what to call and how to call it. This is my code:

```
    #include <efi.h>        // EFI header
    #include <efilib.h>     // EFI library header

    int DisableTimeout(EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable);  // Allows us to call in efi_main

    EFI_STATUS EFIAPI efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {

        InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
        EFI_STATUS Status;

        EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle2 = NULL;

        const CHAR16 *FileName = L"HELLO.efi";
        EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *FilePath;

        uefi_call_wrapper(SystemTable->ConOut->SetAttribute, 1, SystemTable->ConOut, 0x0F); // Set text to white
        uefi_call_wrapper(SystemTable->ConOut->ClearScreen, 1, SystemTable->ConOut);    // Clear screen

        Print(L"Begin boot process.\nBooting from system with ");
        Print(SystemTable->FirmwareVendor);
        Print(L" firmware.\n");

        Status = DisableTimeout(SystemTable);   // Pass system table so it can shut off timer


Status = SystemTable->BootServices->LoadImage(TRUE, ImageHandle, FilePath, NULL, 0, &ImageHandle2);
    Status = SystemTable->BootServices->StartImage(ImageHandle2, NULL, NULL);


    Print(L"Boot complete.\n");
    WaitForSingleEvent(SystemTable->ConIn->WaitForKey, 0);  // Wait for keypress

        return EFI_SUCCESS;
    }
```

The DisableTimeout() is a function I made.

Sorry, I am very new to UEFI development.

Comment: I found this page: http://wiki.phoenix.com/wiki/index.php/EFI_BOOT_SERVICES#LoadImage.28.29 but I still don't know what to feed in or what preludes it. I want to just use a predefined path.